# Get instance from a dictionary of types and instances

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, unity-game-engine, types

I have a simple service manager called `ServiceManager` that has two methods. `Create()` creates an instance of a service. `Provide()` returns a service that has previously been created.

I have a basic implementation that works but am wondering if there's a cleaner way. This is my basic implementation of the `ServiceManager`:

```
public class ServiceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<Type, MonoBehaviour> services = new Dictionary<Type, MonoBehaviour>();

    public void Create<T>() where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Create service
        GameObject serviceObject = new GameObject(typeof(T).Name);
        serviceObject.transform.SetParent(transform); // make service GO our child
        T service = serviceObject.AddComponent<T>(); // attach service to GO

        // Register service
        services.Add(typeof(T), service);
    }

    public T Provide<T>() where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        return (T)services[typeof(T)]; // notice the cast to T here
    }
}
```

Using the service is simple:

```
public class ServiceTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        // Creating services
        ServiceManager services = FindObjectOfType<ServiceManager>();
        services.Create<MapService>();
        services.Create<InteractionService>();
    }

    private void Example()
    {
        // Get a service
        ServiceManager services = FindObjectOfType<ServiceManager>();
        MapService map = services.Provide<MapService>();
        // do whatever you want with map
    }
}
```

My question is about `ServiceManager.Provide()`. Notice the cast to T after getting the item from the dictionary. This feel very unclean and makes me wonder if I am missing something about how generics work in C#. Are there other/better ways to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: *"This feel very unclean"* -- not to me it doesn't. To me it looks fine. Generics aren't going to do anything magic for you there. It's a cast; they're not in the language by accident. You're good.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Alright, thank you! Just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I wasn't understanding. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to improve here. The cast is necessary because the dictionary value type is a `MonoBehaviour`. *You* know that it is actually `T`, but the compiler doesn't. You have to tell that by casting.

You did well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything. Cheers.

Comment: I think there's better than a dictionary with casts, if there is only one instance per type as there appears to be. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only ever one instance per type, then there is better. Consider a static generic type

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ServiceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // If this T confuses you from the generic T used elsewhere, rename it
    public static Transform T { get; private set; }

    void Awake()
    {
        T = transform;
    }

    public T Provide<T>() where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        return ServiceMap<T>.service; // no cast required
    }
}

static class ServiceMap<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static readonly T service;

    static ServiceMap()
    {
        // Create service
        GameObject serviceObject = new GameObject(typeof(T).Name);
        serviceObject.transform.SetParent(ServiceManager.T); // make service GO our child
        service = serviceObject.AddComponent<T>(); // attach service to GO
    }
}
```

Using the service is simple:

```
public class ServiceTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        // no need to Create services
        // They will be created when Provide is first called on them
        // Though if you want them up and running at Start, call Provide
        // on each here.
    }

    private void Example()
    {
        // Get a service
        ServiceManager services = FindObjectOfType<ServiceManager>();
        MapService map = services.Provide<MapService>();
        // do whatever you want with map
    }
}
```

Also, if you have multiple `ServiceManagers` then this won't work.